# Which Sanderson works are part of the Cosmere and which aren't?

Tags: cosmere, brandon-sanderson

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandon_Sanderson):

> The Cosmere is the name of the universe in which many of Sanderson's books exist. This idea came from his desire to create an epic length series without requiring readers to buy a ridiculous number of books. Because of that, he hides connections to his other works within each book, creating this "hidden epic". In the end, the Cosmere Cycle will include between 32-36 books.

But Wikipedia doesn't specify precisely *which* of Sanderson's books are part of the Cosmere. It's certainly not all of them, but I'm not sure exactly which ones are the exceptions.

Sanderson's [own website](http://brandonsanderson.com/books/where-do-i-start/), as well as [this SFF.SE question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85905/31394), both mention various books which are part of the Cosmere, but they don't state whether this is *all* the Cosmere books published so far, nor do they give proper lists of non-Cosmere Sanderson books.

**I'm looking for an exhaustive list of Sanderson's works, clearly split into Cosmere and non-Cosmere books/series.**

<sub>The motivation for this question is [this meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10284/31394) - before starting to retag, I want to be sure which [brandon-sanderson](/questions/tagged/brandon-sanderson)</sub> <sup>questions are actually [cosmere](/questions/tagged/cosmere) questions. But you don't need to worry about meta and tagging to answer this.</sup>

Comment: just fyi the Coppermind's [bibliography](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Bibliography) page is kept up to date with any developments, and the page on the Cosmere has a [section](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Cosmere#Bibliography_of_the_Cosmere) about the books involved and their relative ordering

Comment: The simple rule of thumb for Brandon's work is, if it mentions Earth or is set on Earth, it's not Cosmere, otherwise it is.  I'm not aware of any stories of his that violate this rule, and he's specifically said on multiple occasions that Earth does not exist in the same universe as the Cosmere.

Comment: @MasonWheeler The Magic: the Gathering novel he wrote starring the Planeswalker Davriel Kane also isn’t a part of Cosmere, presumably.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## List of Cosmere works

The Cosmere series is on-going, so the works that are part of it will grow. However, the more recent works set in the Cosmere have been more clearly part of a shared universe, with crossover characters (like Hoid) and concepts (like Shards and Adonalsium itself, how magic works in general). It should be pretty easy to decide if a novel is Cosmere or not based on this.

At this point, these works are part of the Cosmere; everything else published as of February 2023 is *not* a Cosmere work:

**The Mistborn series** (set on Scadrial):

Era 1

- *The Final Empire*
- *The Well of Ascension*
- *The Hero of Ages*
- *The Eleventh Metal*
- *Mistborn: Secret History* (novella)

Era 2

- *The Alloy of Law*
- *Shadows of Self*
- *The Bands of Mourning*
- *The Lost Metal*
- *Allomancer Jak and the Pits of Eltania* (short story)

**The Stormlight Archive** (set on Roshar):

- *The Way of Kings*
- *Words of Radiance*
- *Edgedancer* (novella)
- *Oathbringer*
- *Dawnshard* (novella)
- *Rhythm of War*

**The Elantris series** (set on Sel):

- *Elantris*
- *The Emperor's Soul* (novella)
- *The Hope of Elantris* (short story)

**The White Sand series** (set on Taldain):

- *White Sand vol 1.*
- *White Sand vol 2.*
- *White Sand vol 3.*
- *White Sand Omnibus* (volumes 1-3 with some additional content)

**Standalone/single works**:

- *Warbreaker* (set on Nalthis)
- *Shadows for Silence in the Forests of Hell* (set on Threnody)
- *Sixth of the Dusk* (set on First of the Sun)
- *Tress of the Emerald Sea* (set on Lumar)
- *Yumi and the Nightmare Painter* (set on Komashi)
- *The Sunlit Man* (set on Canticle)

## List of non-Cosmere works

Any other work by Sanderson would be considered a non-Cosmere work. There's a lot of short stories published in anthologies that don't really have their own series name or title, and wouldn't really have tags to begin with. There's a list on Wikipedia but I have no idea how complete it is. The main novels/novellas he has published include:

**The Wheel of Time** (collaborative):

- *The Gathering Storm*
- *Towers of Midnight*
- *A Memory of Light*

**The Reckoners series**:

- *Steelheart*
- *Mitosis* (novella)
- *Firefight*
- *Calamity*
- *Lux* (audibook)

**The Rithmatist series**:

- *The Rithmatist*
- *The Aztlanian*

**The Alcatraz series**:

- *Alcatraz Versus the Evil Librarians*
- *The Scrivener's Bones*
- *The Knights of Crystallia*
- *The Shattered Lens*
- *The Dark Talent*

**Infinity Blade series** (based on the video game):

- *Infinity Blade: Awakening*
- *Infinity Blade: Redemption*

**Legion series**:

- *Legion*
- *Legion: Skin Deep*
- *Legion: Lies of the Beholder*

**Skyward Series**:

- *Defending Elysium* (novella)
- *Skyward*
- *Starsight*
- *Cytonic*
- *Defiant*

**Standalone books**:

- *Perfect State*
- *The Frugal Wizard’s Handbook for Surviving Medieval England*

Comment: Is this just the Cosmere works? I'd like a list of the non-Cosmere ones too (so that I know which tags to watch out for while merging). In fact, didn't you have a non-Cosmere list at first and then shadow-edit it out?

Comment: nope, i don't even know all of his non-cosmere works, there's a number of one-offs. I'll go grab a bibliography.

Comment: This answer has been really helpful in sorting out the outlying [tag:brandon-sanderson]-tagged questions before the merge into [tag:cosmere]. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: You forgot Children of the Nameless, his Magic: the Gathering novella.

Comment: While The Emperor's Soul takes place on Sel, I wouldn't consider part of 'the Elantris series'  - they're totally unrelated works, and it's possible to read both without ever realizing they take place on the same planet.

Comment: I've updated the cosmere section. The non-cosmere section can still use an update.